# Deleting Outliers in a regression model

Tags: r, linear-model

Working on a linear regression problem in R, I created a first model

```
flights_lm = lm(freq~dist+capa+nbrt+depf+lcco+prbi)
```

where freq is frequency, dist is distance, capa for capacity, nrt stands for number of roads, fuel is depf. I then started to remove variables which doesn't contribute to the model explination, and ended up with
 Coefficients:

```
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
 (Intercept) 2.822e+02  6.239e+03   0.045  0.96400    
 nbrt        8.072e+01  6.515e+00  12.390  < 2e-16 ***
 depf        3.052e-05  1.128e-05   2.704  0.00784 **
```

meaning that the frequency was well explained by nbrt and depf. Then I proceeded to remove points that affect the model (I guess they're called outliers). for that I used the R function `Cooks.distance` and couldn't get rid of all the points. each time I apply the function and plot it according to the model some other points pop out of the 0.65 limit that set for the model.
I have one doubt though, once I remove the points, Do I need to restart the process from the beginning (meaning creating the model with all the variables then delete each that p-value is the biggest until I get all the p values <0.05)
or just delete the points and plot the model ?
Another question is :  could the function log help me with this case ?

Comment: Do not remove any points from your data (unless you have a convincing independent justification, e.g., some lab notes indicating problems during measurements). If your only problem are influential values (i.e., you are sure that you are using the correct model framework and don't need e.g. a GLM), you could use robust regression. I like function `lmrob` from package robustbase. However, with the meager information in your question, I'd at least suspect that a GLM might be more appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

We know that the $i^{th}$ Cook's distance is defined as: $$D_{i} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} (\hat{Y}_{j}- \hat{Y}_{j(i)})^{2}}{p \ \text{MSE}}$$

where

- $\hat{Y}_j$ is the prediction from the full regression model for observation $j$
- $\hat{Y}_{j(i)}$ is the prediction for observation $j$ from a refitted regression model with observation $i$ omitted
- $p$ is the number of parameters in the model
- $\text{MSE}$ is the mean square error of the model

In your example, $p=2$ (number of independent variables). So I think you are fine with just deleting the points and looking the various Cook's distances since you already initially removed the non-significant variables.

Comment: The downvote reminds me that many people, including myself, would be troubled at the implicit agreement made here with the OP's strategy of repeatedly removing high-leverage points without any further consideration. That creates all kinds of problems concerning the integrity of the data, the meaning of any formal tests, and the interpretation of interval estimates. Both you and the OP should consider a much more nuanced approach to outlier identification and processing, as discussed in some of our threads about outliers (which you can search).

Comment: @whuber: Thanks, should I remove my answer?

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I read the article they were very instructive, but still they don't resolve the problem, when I get my final model and i plot it, the residuals don't follow a 0,1 normal distribution. I know that, like mentioned in some topics here, that I need a valid model, before thinking about outliers, but do outliers have an influence on the resudials qqplot being flat and not following the normal distribution or should I try log the data to get the accurate residual plot